# Exam Class start page numbering on running footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, exam

I want to start page numbering on the second page. There is a footer and and running footer. I do not want page number on first page. I have tried thispagestyle{empty, plan} removes headers and footers. Tried \pagenumber{gobble}  \pagenumber{arabic} Tried clear page set counter {page}{1} I have been at this two days. Can someone put me out of my misery?

```
MWW`  % !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{fontspec}% need for arial from top line
\setmainfont{Arial}% needed for arial from top line
\usepackage{array}% this is need to centre data
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} % this centres data

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.25pt}% so you can see table boarders at 100%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}% need to colour table 
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0.0,0.0}

\usepackage[%
colorlinks=true,%
urlcolor=blue%
]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref


%\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion\hfill\thepoints}} puts text below questions
%\qformat{\textbf{Step \thequestion\hfill\thepoints}}
%\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Step ~\thequestion.}

%\usepackage{enumitem}% need for list 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{geometry}



\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71} % needed for coloured cube
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}


\pagestyle{headandfoot}



\firstpageheader{  }  
{\raisebox{-50pt}{ \footnotesize
        \hspace{-0.2cm}      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|C|} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Qualification National code and Title &   ********** \\
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Unit/s National code/s and title     &  ********* \\
            \hline
\end{tabularx}}}
{\large \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{ Assessment Submission and Feedback}}}
\extraheadheight[120pt]{120pt}% addded <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\runningheader{ }
{\raisebox{-40pt}{ \footnotesize \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|C|} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Qualification national code and title &   ********* \\
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Unit/s national code/s and title     & ********** \\
            \hline
\end{tabularx}}}
{\large \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{ Assessment Task 1}}}

%move headers up or and down 
\extraheadheight[120pt]{120pt}% addded <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\globalcolorstrue

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{parskip}% this stops indent of first line in paragraph

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
% The above are need to get left an right y axis in right places otherwise on top of each other

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta} % needed for tikz pictures

\usepackage{amssymb}% this is need for tick box






\firstpagefootrule

%



\runningfooter{ ****  }{*****  }{ ***** \\      Page \thepage\ of \numpages    } 

\firstpagefooter{\footnotesize{ Issue date:  } }{   }{   } %\footnotesize{ Page \thepage\ of \numpages    } 


\usepackage{amsmath}% needed for fractions dfrac

\extraheadheight[2.25cm]{2.25cm}% this gives extra height by moving upwards

\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \newgeometry{left=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, top= 5.25cm,right=1cm}
    
    
    
    
    \begin{center}
        
        
        \vspace*{-2\baselineskip} % this moves the table up to the header   
        \begingroup
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \hspace*{-\leftmargin}\begin{tabular}{|l|p{4cm}  p{4cm} | p{1cm}  | c |}
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Assessment \#  and title & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
            Lecturer name & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}     \\
            \hline
            Student name    &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}          \\
            \hline
            Student ID number   &    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   \\
            \hline
            Telephone contact number    &   & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Email:}             \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{% 
                \small{ By completing and submitting this signed form to my lecturer, I am stating that :  
                    % \begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{\alph*})]
                        \begin{enumerate}[a.]
                            \vspace{-0.3cm}     \item The attached submission is completely my own work
                            \vspace{-0.3cm} \item I have correctly cited all sources of information used in this  work (if required)
                            \vspace{-0.3cm} \item I have kept a copy of this assessment (where practicable)
                            \vspace{-0.3cm}     \item   I understand a copy of my assessment will be kept by ***** for their records 
                            \vspace{-0.3cm}     \item   I understand my assessment may be selected for use in the ******* validation and audit process to ensure student assessment meets requirements 
                            \vspace{-0.8cm} 
                        \end{enumerate} 
                }}      \\                                
                \hline
                \cellcolor{blue!20}    Student Signature   &    &    &   \cellcolor{blue!20} Date       &                \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \endgroup
        \small{\textbf{\underline{Assessor please note:} Where verbal clarification has been sought from a student to gather additional assessment evidence from an assessment item, question/s and response/s must be recorded, signed, and dated by the assessor, against the relevant assessment item/s.}} 
        
        
        \textbf{Submission 1 \,  $ \square$ \, Assessment Result Satisfactory / Not Yet Satisfactory} (please circle) \textbf{Date:}    \hrulefill \\
        
        \vspace{-0.4cm}
        
        \textit{To satisfy requirements for this assessment, you need to complete the following: }
        \vspace{-0.2cm}
        
        \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
        
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        \textbf{Submission 2 \,  $ \square$ \, Assessment Result Satisfactory / Not Yet Satisfactory} (please circle) \textbf{Date:}    \hrulefill \\
        
        \vspace{-0.4cm}
        
        \textit{To satisfy requirements for this assessment, you need to complete the following: }
        
        \vspace{-0.1cm}
        
        \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
        
        \vspace{-0.1cm}
        
        \textbf{Student Feedback}
        
        \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
        
        \vspace{0.4cm}
        
        \textbf{Lecturer Signature:} \underline{\hspace{6cm}} \textbf{Student Signature:} \hrulefill
        
        
        \restoregeometry
        
        
        \newpage
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment type (\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}     ):}}  
        
        
        %$ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} Questioning  (Oral/Written)
        
        \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}    \hspace{0.2cm} 
        Questioning  (Oral/Written)   
        
        
        $ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} Practical Demonstration
        
        $ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} $3^{rd}$ Party Report
        
        $ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} Other - Project/Portfolio(please specify)
        
        %\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}    \hspace{0.2cm} Other - Project/Portfolio(please specify)  { \color{red}{ .}}
        
        
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment Resources:}}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                *******
                
                
            }%
        }
        
        
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment Instructions:}}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                
                
                
            }%
            ********************************************************************************        }   \\
        
        xxxx to write generic assessment instructions
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment Instrument:}}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \textbf{IMPORTANT NOTE:}\\
                **********.
                
            }% 
        }       
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        \newpage    
        
        
        
            
    
        
        
        \begin  {questions}
        
        \question
        
        Link the appropriate units of measurements by putting arrows from left to right 
        
        
        \newpage
    
        \question
        
        What does the line in the middle of each side of the square tell you?  % how many vertical and horizotanl lines does it have
            
        
        \end {questions}
        
        
        
        
        
        
    \end{document}
                 `
```

Comment: IIRC, exam class does not play well with the geometry package.  I can't offer more help since MikTeX seems to have lost exam_doc and chrome refuses to download PDFs despite the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use coverpages.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB

\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{fontspec}% need for arial from top line
\setmainfont{Arial}% needed for arial from top line
\usepackage{array}% this is need to centre data
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|} % this centres data

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.25pt}% so you can see table boarders at 100%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}% need to colour table 
\definecolor{Red}{rgb}{0.8,0.0,0.0}

\usepackage[%
colorlinks=true,%
urlcolor=blue%
]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref


%\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion\hfill\thepoints}} puts text below questions
%\qformat{\textbf{Step \thequestion\hfill\thepoints}}
%\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Step ~\thequestion.}

%\usepackage{enumitem}% need for list 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71} % needed for coloured cube
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}


\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\coverheader{  }  
{\raisebox{-50pt}{ \footnotesize
        \hspace{-0.2cm}      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|C|} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Qualification National code and Title &   ********** \\
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Unit/s National code/s and title     &  ********* \\
            \hline
\end{tabularx}}}
{\large \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{ Assessment Submission and Feedback}}}
\extraheadheight[120pt]{120pt}% addded <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\coverextraheadheight[120pt]{120pt}% addded <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\header{ }
{\raisebox{-40pt}{ \footnotesize \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|C|} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Qualification national code and title &   ********* \\
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Unit/s national code/s and title     & ********** \\
            \hline
\end{tabularx}}}
{\large \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{ Assessment Task 1}}}

%move headers up or and down
%\extraheadheight[120pt]{120pt}% addded <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\coverfootrule

\coverfooter{\footnotesize{ Issue date:  } }{   }{   } %\footnotesize{ Page \thepage\ of \numpages    } 

\globalcolorstrue
\footer{ ****  }{*****  }{ ***** \\      Page \thepage\ of \numpages    } 



\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{parskip}% this stops indent of first line in paragraph

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
% The above are need to get left an right y axis in right places otherwise on top of each other

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta} % needed for tikz pictures

\usepackage{amssymb}% this is need for tick box

\usepackage{amsmath}% needed for fractions dfrac

\extraheadheight[2.25cm]{2.25cm}% this gives extra height by moving upwards
\coverextraheadheight[2.25cm]{2.25cm}% this gives extra height by moving upwards

\begin{document}
            
    \newgeometry{left=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, top= 5.25cm,right=1cm}
    

\begin{coverpages}
    \begin{center}        
        
        \vspace*{-2\baselineskip} % this moves the table up to the header   
        \begingroup
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
        \hspace*{-\leftmargin}\begin{tabular}{|l|p{4cm}  p{4cm} | p{1cm}  | c |}
            \hline
            \cellcolor{blue!20}Assessment \#  and title & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{} \\
            \hline
            Lecturer name & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}     \\
            \hline
            Student name    &  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}          \\
            \hline
            Student ID number   &    \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   \\
            \hline
            Telephone contact number    &   & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Email:}             \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{% 
                \small{ By completing and submitting this signed form to my lecturer, I am stating that :  
                    % \begin{enumerate}[label=(\textbf{\alph*})]
                        \begin{enumerate}[a.]
                            \vspace{-0.3cm}     \item The attached submission is completely my own work
                            \vspace{-0.3cm} \item I have correctly cited all sources of information used in this  work (if required)
                            \vspace{-0.3cm} \item I have kept a copy of this assessment (where practicable)
                            \vspace{-0.3cm}     \item   I understand a copy of my assessment will be kept by ***** for their records 
                            \vspace{-0.3cm}     \item   I understand my assessment may be selected for use in the ******* validation and audit process to ensure student assessment meets requirements 
                            \vspace{-0.8cm} 
                        \end{enumerate} 
                }}      \\                                
                \hline
                \cellcolor{blue!20}    Student Signature   &    &    &   \cellcolor{blue!20} Date       &                \\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \endgroup
        \small{\textbf{\underline{Assessor please note:} Where verbal clarification has been sought from a student to gather additional assessment evidence from an assessment item, question/s and response/s must be recorded, signed, and dated by the assessor, against the relevant assessment item/s.}} 
        
        
        \textbf{Submission 1 \,  $ \square$ \, Assessment Result Satisfactory / Not Yet Satisfactory} (please circle) \textbf{Date:}    \hrulefill \\
        
        \vspace{-0.4cm}
        
        \textit{To satisfy requirements for this assessment, you need to complete the following: }
        \vspace{-0.2cm}
        
        \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
        
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        
        \textbf{Submission 2 \,  $ \square$ \, Assessment Result Satisfactory / Not Yet Satisfactory} (please circle) \textbf{Date:}    \hrulefill \\
        
        \vspace{-0.4cm}
        
        \textit{To satisfy requirements for this assessment, you need to complete the following: }
        
        \vspace{-0.1cm}
        
        \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
        
        \vspace{-0.1cm}
        
        \textbf{Student Feedback}
        
        \framebox[\textwidth]{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
        
        \vspace{0.4cm}
        
        \textbf{Lecturer Signature:} \underline{\hspace{6cm}} \textbf{Student Signature:} \hrulefill
        
        
  \end{coverpages}   
       
        \restoregeometry        
        
        \newpage

        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment type (\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}     ):}}  
                
        %$ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} Questioning  (Oral/Written)
        
        \makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}    \hspace{0.2cm} 
        Questioning  (Oral/Written)   
                
        $ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} Practical Demonstration
        
        $ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} $3^{rd}$ Party Report
        
        $ \square$ \hspace{0.2cm} Other - Project/Portfolio(please specify)
        
        %\makebox[0pt][l]{$\square$}\raisebox{.15ex}{\hspace{0.1em}$\checkmark$}    \hspace{0.2cm} Other - Project/Portfolio(please specify)  { \color{red}{ .}}
                
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment Resources:}}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                *******
                                
            }%
        }
                
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment Instructions:}}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                               
                
            }%
            ********************************************************************************        }   \\
        
        xxxx to write generic assessment instructions
        \textbf{\textcolor{Red}{Assessment Instrument:}}
        
        \noindent\fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \textbf{IMPORTANT NOTE:}\\
                **********.
                
            }% 
        }
               
        \newpage    
                
        \begin  {questions}
        
        \question
        
        Link the appropriate units of measurements by putting arrows from left to right 
        
        
        \newpage
        
        \question
        
        What does the line in the middle of each side of the square tell you?  % how many vertical and horizotanl lines does it have
        
        
        \end {questions}
        
    \end{document}
```

[image]